# I am not able to connect to the headless "Ubuntu" remote virtual machine (virtual box)

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, oracle-linux

I cannot connect to the headless "Ubuntu" remote virtual machine which I created using virtual box. I've installed the virtual machine and configured it on my oracle linux server using ssh connection. Later I started the virtual machine using the following command:  `vboxheadless --startvm "vbox_test" &` and it started successfully. So now I have to configure the Ubuntu on it. But unfortunately I am not able to connect to the VM: neither via ssh connection nor through RDP connection. VRDE Server is listening on port 3389. If I try to connect to VM using SSH I get the following error: Connection refused. Despite the fact I can connect to the server using SSH without specifying any ports like 3389. Also I cannot connect to the VM using Microsoft Remote Desktop. What can I do to connect to the VM?

Comment: 1) Have you checked, if the daemon is actually listening on this port? [Here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-check-if-port-is-in-use-command/) are multiple examples how to get a list of applications listening.
2) Have you checked, that the port isn't blocked by iptables/ip6tables? [Here](https://www.e2enetworks.com/help/knowledge-base/how-to-open-ports-on-iptables-in-a-linux-server/) are examples how you could list or change the configuration.

Comment: I checked if the daemon is listening on the port, the daemon seems to listen to this port.Also I checked the iptables and cannot find the port in the list.

Comment: Then you should try to whitelist/add the port and see if it helps.

Comment: I tried to whitelist the port using the steps described [here](https://www.e2enetworks.com/help/knowledge-base/how-to-open-ports-on-iptables-in-a-linux-server/), but unfortunately the connection  is still refused...

Comment: During startup - is it showing that VRDE server is listening on correct port and not on a specific and wrong IP? You are using MSTSC.exe as normal RDP client?

Comment: And another idea - if you don't start it headless, can you connect to itself from within Ubuntu?

Comment: During startup of the virtual machine there are no errors. Yes, I downloaded MSTSC to use it as RDP client, but I didn't use it before. What do you mean by connection to itself from within Ubuntu? I installed the vm on the oracle linux server without GUI. And now I'm trying to connect to the Ubuntu VM. Should I start it without headless mode and try to connect to it using SSH within the linux server?